# The Chase Method

Tags: relational-database, database-normalization

My relation R(A,B,C,R,S,T) which is broken down to:

R1(A, B, C)

R2(R,S,T, C)

with dependencies:

```
A --> B
B --> C
R --> S
S --> T
```

I want to check with the chase method wheter there is a lossless join or not. I think I understand other relations I have done with the method.

**I want to know if I have understood the method correctly:**

```
|----||----||----||----||----||----|
| A  || B  || C  || R  || S  || T  |
|----||----||----||----||----||----|
| a  || b  || c  || r1 || s1 || t1 |
|----||----||----||----||----||----|
| a1 || b1 || c  || r  || s  || t  |
|----||----||----||----||----||----|
```

Is this a dead end? **I'm I only allowed to remove a subscript if the letter on the left side of the dependency is not already subscripted?**

Comment: Hi. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use a link/image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. @VinothRaja  Please do not inline links inappropriately. Use text whenever possible. Either replace a link to a table by code block formatted tabular text or, much better, comment to tell the poster to do it.. Your edit shouldn't have been approved.

Comment: If you want us to check your work please show it, not just a milestone, so we don't have to redo it.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want me to add, what I generally want is the last question in bold answered to see if I have understand the method correctly. If so then the tables will be unchanged after I have checked for all dependencies.